# Static driver declared in Junit Script causing failure in Jmeter for multiple loads

Tags: junit, jmeter, load-testing

In Junit, in BeforeClass menthod the chorme driver can be only static. Please refer the code below:-

```
static WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

@BeforeClass
  public void beforeTest() {

    System.out.println("Before Test");    
    String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\JmeterJunit\\eclipse\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe" ;  
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);  
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
    options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--ignore-certificate-errors");  

    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);  

    driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }
```

As the driver gets static, in multiple loads testing, the 1st browser launched works successfully, but the execution in browser launched further gets failed. I think the main reason is the static driver declared.

Comment: I don't quite follow what is the problem here? Could you please elaborate on how your test plan looks like, at least?

Answer (score 0):

Consider migrating to [JUnit 5](https://junit.org/junit5/) where there is [@BeforeAll](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/BeforeAll.html) annotation and the function annotated with it doesn't have to be static given you annotate the class with [@TestInstance](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.2.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestInstance.html)

Example code:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
public class SomeClass {

    private ChromeDriver driver;


    @BeforeAll
    void beforeTest() {

        System.out.println("Before Test");
        String chromeDriverPath = "C:\\\\JmeterJunit\\\\eclipse\\\\chromedriver_win32\\\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--ignore-certificate-errors");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    void testSomething() {

    }
}
```

It would be also a good idea to wrap the WebDriver into [ThreadLocal](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal).

Also be aware that there is a [WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/) which is fully compatible with JMeter threads model so you won't have to worry about instantiation, [thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety), etc.